# Calculating the Difference Between Actual Start Date and Baseline Start Date

Tags: ms-project

I'm new to MS Project. I want to calculate the difference between the baseline start date and the actual start date.

Does anyone know how to calculate that? I've seen in another forum that I need to use a formula to calculate that.

Comment: Your question has drawn my attention and I've googled this example: "You set the baseline for your project a month ago. At that time, the "Develop estimate" task was scheduled to start on January 3. The task was actually started on January 8. In the Task Sheet view, you have added the Baseline Start and Actual Start fields. The Baseline Start field for this task contains January 3, and the Actual Start field contains January 8." Here is the link to actual resource where you can find more detailed explanation about the difference between baseline start date and actual start date:
https://suppor

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to calculate it- Just add the 'Start Variance' column into your view- that will automatically show the difference between Start and Baseline Start.

Whilst this is not the same as Actual Start, it is more useful for calculating slippages as it works on tasks for which no work has yet been done. At the point you enter actual work then MS-Project moves Start to match Actual Start.